Don't know why i am getting multiple entries with same email id and same provider in firebase authentication. How to avoid it? (Flutter)
I am encountering an issue where multiple entries are being created in my Firebase Authentication database with same provider. As shown in the attached image, duplicate entries are being generated.

I guess there is nothing to do with the code but I am attaching just in case of you need it
{
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          try {
                            if (!privacyStatus) {
                              appFlutterToast("Please check privacy policy check box!");
                              return;
                            }
                            QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection("users")
                                .where("username", isEqualTo: usernameController.text.trim())
                                .get();

                            if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                              appFlutterToast("Username Not Available");

                              return;
                            }

                            final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: emailController.text.trim(),
                              password: passwordController.text,
                            );
                            if (credential.user == null) {
                              appFlutterToast("Error");
                            } else {
                              appFlutterToast("Registered Successful");
                              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(credential.user!.uid).set(
                                  {'id': credential.user!.uid, 'uid': credential.user!.uid, "username": usernameController.text.trim()},
                                  SetOptions(merge: true));
                              SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                              await context.read<UserProvider>().getCurrentAuth(context);
                              await pref.setBool('logged', true);
                              ///MAIN LANDING PAGE
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyCardsScreen()),
                              );
                            }
                          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                            if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                              appFlutterToast("The password provided is too weak.");
                              // print('The password provided is too weak.');
                            } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
                              appFlutterToast("account already exists for that email.");

                              // print('The account already exists for that email.');
                            } else {
                              appFlutterToast(e.message ?? "Error");
                            }
                          } catch (e) {
                            // print(e);
                          }
                          // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          //   const SnackBar(content: Text('User added')),
                          // );
                        }

                        // await users.add({
                        //   'username': nameText,
                        //   'password': passwordText,
                        // }).then((value) => print("user added"));
                      }

Final result should be just one entry for one email.
Thank you in advance.

I wasn't able to replicate this issue. Creating users with same email address on both console and app throw email already exists error.

We are having the same issue! The same email with the same provider is creating multiple accounts for no reason. We also use Flutter for front-end.
